# Throwing Runntime Error Using Universal Image Loader Library

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, viewpagerindicator

Hello Friend I am Using Universal Image Loader To Slide Image From Json 
But I don't know Why its Giving Illegal Argument

here Is my Code Debugger jump to error

```
if (result != null) {
    if (products != null && products.size() != 0) {

        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ImageSlideAdapter(
            activity, products, HomeFragment.this));

        mIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        imgNameTxt.setText(""
                + ((Product) products.get(mViewPager
                        .getCurrentItem())).getName());
        runnable(products.size());
        handler.postDelayed(animateViewPager,
                ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);
    }
```

the error is  on the

```
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ImageSlideAdapter(
            activity, products, HomeFragment.this));
```

And Here Is My Slideradaptor Class

```
public class ImageSlideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoadingListener imageListener;
    FragmentActivity activity;
    List<Product> products;
    HomeFragment homeFragment;

    public ImageSlideAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<Product> products,
            HomeFragment homeFragment) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.homeFragment = homeFragment;
        this.products = products;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc().build();

        imageListener = new ImageDisplayListener();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vp_image, container, false);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.image_display);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                Fragment fragment = null;
                Log.d("position adapter", "" + position);
                Product product = (Product) products.get(position);
                arguments.putParcelable("singleProduct", product);

                // Start a new fragment
                fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = activity
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,
                        ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                transaction.addToBackStack(ProductDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                transaction.commit();*/
            }
        });
        imageLoader.displayImage(
                ((Product) products.get(position)).getImageUrl(), mImageView,
                options, imageListener);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    private static class ImageDisplayListener extends
            SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections
                .synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please Tell Me Where I m Doing Wrong

and My Logcat Giving ME

```
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.checkConfiguration(ImageLoader.java:340)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.displayImage(ImageLoader.java:179)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at com.wie.trandyclothing.services.ImageSlideAdapter.instantiateItem(ImageSlideAdapter.java:89)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at com.wie.trandyclothing.services.ImageSlideAdapter.instantiateItem(ImageSlideAdapter.java:1)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:987)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:447)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at    com.wie.trandyclothing.HomeFragment$RequestImgTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:291)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at com.wie.trandyclothing.HomeFragment$RequestImgTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:1)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 10:54:05.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: sorry, there is no TLTR version of exceptions ... you have to read whole exception and you will get what is wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initalize the ImageLoader with the confugurations in your Adapter Constructor

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext()));
```

change your constructor like this

```
public ImageSlideAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<Product> products,
    HomeFragment homeFragment) {
      this.activity = activity;
      this.homeFragment = homeFragment;
      this.products = products;
      options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc().build();
      ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
       imageListener = new ImageDisplayListener();
}
```